# How to switch locale in Spring REST docs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-restdocs

I have a `@RestController` where one of the arguments of a controller method is `Locale`

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public Survey getSurvey( @PathVariable("id") SurveyId surveyId, 
                         Locale locale ) { ... }
```

I have a working integration test (using RestAssured) where I can switch locale by setting the `Accept-Language` header.

I now want to document this using Spring REST docs as well. Setting the header in this case (using MockMvc) does not work.

My test something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public void SurveyControllerDocumentation {

    // Test methods here
    ...

    // Application context for documentation test
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public static class TestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SurveyController controller(MessageSource messageSource) {
            return new SurveyController(userService(), messageSource, surveyService());
        }

        @Bean
        public UserService userService() {
            return mock(UserService.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public SurveyService surveyService() {
            return mock(SurveyService.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public CustomEditorsControllerAdvice customEditorsControllerAdvice() {
            return new CustomEditorsControllerAdvice();
        }

        @Bean
        public RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler exceptionHandler() {
            return new RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some bean that I need to explicitly add to my test context that does the locale injection?

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.3 (which has Spring 4.2.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `Locale` using the [`locale(Locale)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#locale-java.util.Locale-) method on the request builder:

```
mockMvc.perform(
    get("/")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .locale(Locale.GERMAN))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(document("example"));
```

Comment: Thx. I ended up _also_ adding `.header("Accept-Language", "fr")` so that the `http-request.adoc` shows that header since users of my REST api need to do that to set the locale.